# Can Destiny 2 faction rally gear drop after faction rally ended?

Tags: destiny-2

So first faction rally ended and winner was picked. As far as I understand one can still farm ornaments during this week.

Does it mean, that also faction specific gear is still possible to drop in some engrams?
Or since there are no faction rally tokens at this point, then one has to wait for next rally to continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to wait for the next faction rally in order to earn faction gear again.

Occasionally faction gear can drop from the chests Cayde-6 sells, but they are a rare drop.